# WiFi USB card is not working VirtualBox Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, kali-linux, wifi-configuration

I am trying to define wlan to Kali Virtual Image at VirtualBox which is installed on Mac OS Catalina. I want to monitor wlan0. I defined card as USB 3.0 (port is 3.1 but there is no option for 3.1) to VirtualBox. I have got latest VirtualBox (6.1.12) with latest extension pack. But I still dont have got wlan connection. I tried every solution that I can find online.

```
root@kali#$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0107 TP-Link TL-WN821N Version 5 RTL8192EU > WiFi adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried these:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') 

apt-get install net-tools
apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkm
service network-manager restart

git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
sudo m-a prepare
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

And I enabled PAE/NX at System > Processor

Adapter 1 is set to NAT Network

I tried compat-wireless

I did installed latest Guest Additions

Changed NetworkManager.conf variable managed=false to true

Link to my card: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00194XKXA/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_x_.UfeFbAAEH9RY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00194XKXA)

It supports MAC OS, Windows and Linux

Comment: Did you set up the USB device (the wireless card) in the Guest machine to be powered on by the Guest?  You need Virtual Box Guest Additions installed to do this.

Comment: How I can do that? Solution that I found didn't work at monitoring. Kali Linux sees the adapter at usb list if thats what you are trying to say.

Comment: There is a menu in Virtual Box to connect devices to the Guest machine. See this article to help you.  https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/access-usb-drive-in-virtualbox-guest-os/#:~:text=It%20does%20not%20matter%20whether,on%20USB%20device%20to%20share.

Comment: I am able to connect my adapter to virtual image. But it is not connecting wlan. I have got no clue about why is this happening.

Comment: You need the wireless driver in the Guest for the now connected adapter. There may not be such driver. Kali does not have all wireless drivers.

Comment: I did installed realtek drivers with "apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms" still same.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This solution might fool you like it did to me. After you type "make load" it adds two different wlans (wlan0, wlan1) which is not working. I tried to airmon-ng start wlan0 and wlan1 but it can't see any modems even while I am sitting next to one of them.

I found a way to solve this issue. First you need to download this:
http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p.tar.bz2

Now we need to extract this zipped folder with this command:
tar - jxvf  compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p

After that type these commands:
cd compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p/ && make unload
make load

Now check wireless with "iwconfig" command, this solution worked for me.

UPDATE: This solution might fool you like it did to me. After you type "make load" it adds two different wlans (wlan0, wlan1) which is not working. I tried to airmon-ng start wlan0 and wlan1 but it can't see any modems even while I am sitting next to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution finally after long tries. There is no official drive after Kali 2018 so if you are using 2019 or 2020 you have to install unofficial driver. Like this one:
https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Installation Guide (Kali Linux):

sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms;

git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver;

sudo dkms add .;

sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0;

echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf;

echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules;

echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf;

sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u;

systemctl reboot -i;

After reboot go to terminal again and type "lsmod" and check for the driver. If you see a driver named as 8192eu you are good to go!